# How can I replace html text dynamically?

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, html-input

I'm adding the text "I Tot I Taw a Puddy Tat!" to the top of a page with jQuery this way in the ready function:

```
$("#Twitterati").html("<h3>I Tot I Taw a Puddy Tat!</h3>").append(tweetiePie);
```

...but I want to dynamically replace that placeholder text ("I Tot I Taw a Puddy Tat!") with the contents of this text input control:

```
<input type="text" name="inputQuery" id="inputQuery" placeholder="Enter something" style="display: inline-block;" />
```

...when the Enter key is mashed. How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
$("#inputQuery").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#Twitterati h3").val($("#inputQuery".val()));
    }
});
```

...and this:

```
$("#inputQuery").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#Twitterati h3").replaceWith($("#inputQuery".val()));
    }
});
```

...but neither one did anything, that I could see...

### UPDATE

This is working pretty well, now; but I want the tweets to refresh when the inputQuery val replaces the text/caption/heading, too. IOW, I can change the text from, say, "jquery" to "html5" but the tweets I've got displaying remain the jquery tweets. How can I get that div to refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#inputQuery").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#Twitterati h3").html($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Missing a closing bracket here `$("#inputQuery" <----`
and a extra bracket at last `.val()));   <----`

Answer (score 1):

Fix this line

```
                                        v
$("#Twitterati h3").html($("#inputQuery").val());
```

Use `.html()` instead of `.val()` for the `h3`

Answer (score 1):

replace `"#inputQuery".val()`

with

```
$("#inputQuery").val()
```

CODE IS:

```
$("#inputQuery").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#Twitterati h3").html($("#inputQuery").val());
    }
});
```

Comment: The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing closing braket that leads error and replace .val() with .html because you are replacing text not value

```
$("#Twitterati h3").html($("#inputQuery").val());
```

but your original was

```
$("#inputQuery".val())    //MIssing HERE
```

You can use this also like

```
$("#Twitterati h3").html($(this).val());
```

'this' will automatically indicates the inputQuery

Comment: The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the HTML of the target element. Also, you can use "this" instead of targeting the element by ID again

```
$("#inputQuery").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
        $("#Twitterati h3").html($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Bit Safer

```
$("#inputQuery").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#Twitterati h3").text(this.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you are using `$("#Twitterati h3").html(..`, paste `<script>alert(window);</script>` in `inputQuery` field & press enter. Repeat the same with `$("#Twitterati h3").text(..`... You will know..