# How can I force the contents of a div to refresh?

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, twitter, jquery-ui-tabs

I am now able to replace html text dynamically ([How can I replace html text dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557053/how-can-i-replace-html-text-dynamically)), but I need the tweets to refresh when the inputQuery val replaces the text/caption/heading, too. IOW, I can change the text from, say, "jquery" to "html5" but the tweets I've got displaying remain the jquery tweets. How can I get that div to refresh? The content is in a jqueryUI tab, but that probably doesn't matter.

### UPDATE

This is what I have:

```
$("#inputQuery").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#Twitterpated h3").text(this.value);
        inputQueryText = this.value; 
        loadTweets(); // this concatenates the bits necessary, with inputQueryText in the middle (the "screen name" part)
    }
});
```

...and it doesn't work. That is to say, the text gets changed, and the concatenated twitterUrl is correct, but the page does not refresh.

I got to thinking - maybe the problem is that I'm not clearing the previous entries. How can I clear the html on the call to loadTweets()? I tried:

```
$("#Twitterpated h3").html("");
```

...and:

```
$("#Twitterpated h3").html().val("");
```

...to no avail.

Comment: What code did you use to initially populate the tweets?

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554149/html-javascript-change-div-content

Comment: @KevinB: I call a function; works fine the first time. When I update the html text, I call the function again, with the updated value for the URL, but it does not refresh. It's the val I want, but the page doesn't refresh, so it doesn't help matters.

Comment: It also doesn't help that you haven't shown us said code.

Comment: I was hoping there were some mindreaders reading along.

Comment: @fonz: Hey! It's not really the same question; I'm able to change the html, it's just that it's having no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand but here's what I am thinking of...

When the value in inputQuery changed, refresh your tweets DIV the same way you first load it. Something like this should do the trick:

```
$('#inputQueryId').change(function () {
    // your code here, let's say:
    RefreshTweets($(this).val());
});
```